# Rails Params Parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an params from Rails that I am trying to parse. I am trying to get a vector containing [3,4] given this example.

```
 {"0"=>{"id"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"true"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"4",  "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

Comment: it's very unclear what you are asking here.  Are you asking for a way to parse this?  have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
hash.collect{|k,v| v["id"].to_i if v["_destroy"]=="false"}.compact
#=> [3,4]
```

Or

```
hash.reject{|k,v| v["_destroy"]=="true"}.map{|k,v| v["id"].to_i}
#=> [3,4]
```

Although collecting the whole hash seems to make more sense to me

```
hash.select{|k,v| v["_destroy"]=="false"}
#=> {"1"=>{"id"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"4", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

Or

```
hash.reject{|k,v| v["_destroy"]=="true"}
#=> {"1"=>{"id"=>"3", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"4", "_destroy"=>"false"}}
```